# Не сохраняется сессия при использовании сервлета

Tags: java, servlet, wildfly

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/hello")
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.getWriter().append("Hello world!" + " " + req.getMethod());
        HttpSession session = req.getSession();
        if (session.getAttribute("name") == null) {
            session.setAttribute("Name", " Hello world session");
            resp.getWriter().append(" No session");
        } else {
            resp.getWriter().append((String)session.getAttribute("name"));
        }
    }
}
```

При обновлении страницы, браузер все также показывает "Hello world! GET No session", как сделать, чтобы в сессию записывалось значение?

Comment: А в куках что нибудь есть?

Comment: @BigTows [вот это](https://pp.userapi.com/c830400/v830400917/b1bd7/AsAAR6Ba_-Y.jpg)

 есть

Comment: Вы записываете атрибут с именем `Name`, а пытаетесь получить - с именем `name`. Вот: `session.getAttribute("name") == null`, `session.setAttribute("Name", " Hello world session")`